# Trying to get json_encode to return row names as well as data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm attempting to return the data in JSON format. The desired format is as follows...

```
{ "projects" : [
  {
    "title":"title 1",
    "image":"Image1",
    "subtitle":"subtitle 1",
    "about":"Blah Blah Blah"
  },
  {
    "title":"title 2",
    "image":"Image2",
    "subtitle":"subtitle 2",
    "about":"Blah Blah Blah"
  }
]}
```

The code below gets the data from the database and returns it in the view as JSON data. My overall goal is to return this data in the correct JSON format so then I can query it using mustaches templating tool in the view. The code below works perfectly when I set the values as rows eg..

```
$userInfo["projects"][] = array("title" => $row[0], "subtitle" => $row[1], "about" => $row[3]);
```

However I don't want to use this method because I want the response to automatically return the row names as well as the data. The reason being that if a user adds a new row to the database it will automatically return the response without having to manually add another row in the code.

The code below is my api.php file.

```
function customError($errno, $errstr) {
echo "<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr";
}
//set error handler
set_error_handler("customError");

  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "root";

  $databaseName = "laravel";
  $tableName = "projects";
  //$row ='';

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root');

$return = new stdClass();
$return->projects = array();  

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $tableName"); 

if($result !== false) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
      $return->projects[] = $row;
  }
}

//echo '<pre>';
  //print_r($return);
//echo '</pre>';

echo json_encode($return);
```

When I execute the echo `'<pre>'` above (currently commented out) I get the following result.

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [projects] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Below is the result when I echo the data as JSON. Could someone please help me out.

```
{"projects":[]}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice or tips.

Comment: I don;t understand what you mean by "table names" here.  I don't see anywhere in you ideal JSON example where you list the names of the DB table invovled, and you are in fact only querying a single DB table.  You do need to build you full data structure before serializing to JSON though.  Echoing a bunch of different JSON bits with each loop iteration is not going to return valid JSON to the caller.

Comment: Sorry @MikeBrant I meant the row names. I'll update the question. How would I build a full data structure that would automatically return each row name with the data before serializing to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

you should use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) so you'll have the column's name as the index, instead of a numeric one

Answer (score 0):

If you are insisting on sticking with `mysql_*` (which you shouldn't since they are deprecated),  you would best use `mysql_fetch_object`.  This would simplify your code to this:

```
// initialize object to store return values
$return = new stdClass();
// create empty projects array on return object
$return->projects = array();  

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");

if($result !== false) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
        $return->projects[] = $row;
    }
}

echo json_encode($return);
```

A few notes:

- Here I eliminate the whole if-else condition around whether there are rows in the returned set.  If caller is expecting a well-formatted JSON response, you should give him one, even if it contains no rows. Your approach of providing a JSON-encoded string response upon there being no rows when JSON is expected is bad, as this is not in the officially documented JSON data format. The caller can easily determine there are no rows in the result set and behave accordingly.
- `mysql_fetch_object()` automatically sets column names as property keys, so there is no need at all to retrieve field names in another operation. You could also use `mysql_fetch_assoc` to fetch an associative array (which encodes to JSON object notation just the same). I prefer to think and work with objects though, since that is ultimately what you are going to be encoding to (JSON does not have an associative array concept). I think this makes intent much clearer to the reader of the code.
- I do one single `json_encode()` step at the very end, after the data structure has been built.  This is ONLY way to build valid JSON.
- Again, you REALLY should not be using `mysql_*` functions for new code.  Use `mysqli` or `PDO` both of which have support for fetching objects from the result set

Comment: For some reason I don't get any response with this solution. The page is still returning nothing.

Comment: The only error I seem to get was an expected ')' at the end of the while loop above. I replaced that but still nothing appears on the page.

Comment: Sorry updated my error checking... this is what I'm now getting...

Error: [8192] mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO insteadError

Comment: So I updated the code from mysql to mysqli 

Now I get the following errors..

 [2] mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string givenError: [2] mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 givenError: [2] mysqli_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given{"projects":[]}

Comment: Sorry about the missing parenthesis. I have corrected above.  From your last note, it sounds like you didn't have a successful `mysqli_connect()`.  When writing code, you should check for and log errors at each step (i.e. connect, db select, query). It also seems you need to look at documentation for each `mysqli` function.  You can't simply pass one parameter to `mysqli_query` for example - you must pass both the query and the DB connection.

Comment: So do I pass the connection and query together?
i.e.
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root', 'laravel');
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM projects");

Comment: In your example you would query like this:  `$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT ...');`

Comment: @MarkBrant This seems to get rid of all my errors but I'm still not getting any JSON data back as a response. And no errors at all. Strange

Comment: You must still be getting some kind of error, becauase the script, as is, should at least return `{"projects":[]}`

Comment: yes I'm getting this now,  `{"projects":[false]}`

Sorry about the huge list of comments, I'm new to stack overflow so can't discuss in chat.

Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: You shouldn't get the `false` value in there at all unless you have modified logic to add that in in case of no returned rows in the result set. If that is the case, I would warn against that usage.  It is much cleaner for a client to simply look at the size of the returned array and determine if it is 0 vs. having to determine if the first element in the array is a boolean value or an object representing the first row.

Comment: I have reverted back to where I was before errors began piling, but now getting this error. Am I suppose to define the value of $row? 
`Undefined variable: row{"projects":[null]}`

Comment: Why don't you update your question with latest code.

Comment: @lollipopwizardkid You don't utilize the database name anywhere, you should pass it as fourth parameter to `mysqli_connect()` or explicitly perform `mysql_select_db()`. Again make sure that you are verifying that you get a connection before operating on `$con` (i.e. put in error handling). You should never assume everything just works.